# How do I include a C++ dynamic library project in the build process of my dotnet core project?

Tags: c#, c++, .net-core

I'm looking at a .NET Core project that calls into dynamic library which I create from C++. I basically copied the example discussed in https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/756.

```
// Program.cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace dotnet_pinvoke
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("extern_lib/a.out")]
        public static extern int MyNativeFunction(int x, int y, int z);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.WriteLine(MyNativeFunction(1, 2, 3));
        }
    }
}


// extern_lib/mylib.c
#include <cstdint>

extern "C" std::int32_t MyNativeFunction(int32_t x, int32_t y, int32_t z)
{
    return x + y + z;
}
```

I build with `g++ -std=c++14 -shared  mylib.c` and `dotnet build`.
This works. I'm even pleasantly surprised how quick it worked.
Now I am wondering how to integrate the build process of the C library
into `dotnet build`.

Ideally, `dotnet build` would call `make` or `cmake` to
update the dynamic library if there were changes.
If that's not possible, what is the best alternative?
Creating releases from my C code and referencing those from C# somehow?

[C++ project dependency for .NET Core project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38527221/c-project-dependency-for-net-core-project) is similar but it seems to apply only to Windows and VS.

[This build from the dotnet core repo itself](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/master/src/corehost/cli/setup.cmake) and [this file from the same repo](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/master/src/corehost/build.proj) look like a good starting point. Is it? Can someone explain how it works?

Comment: Why downvote? I researched quite a bit but there wasn't much to find.

Comment: Why not create a NuGet package?

Comment: @JeroenHeier sounds like an interesting idea. Wouldn't I have even more problems there to make sure the C++ code is compiled for various platforms? Can I create a package without uploading it? It looks like I can host my private nuget server but that would be overkill for this project.

Comment: Interesting related issue from 2014-2016: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/402
Mentions libuv package https://github.com/aspnet/libuv-package which supposedly does what I also want to do.